# Zip code confirmation macro for Word or Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

Is there a macro for Excel or Word that will look at a list of addresses and return the zip code?  I have a list of 2000 addresses that need to have the zip codes confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes....kind of.  There are lots of address verification services out there on the web.  At least some of them I've run across have an excel sheet version of their webservice that you can paste data into.

One of the biggest is http://www.melissadata.com/.  Not sure if they have an excel ready version, but there's probably something they can do for you.